# @Property in css isn't updating its value when I'm setting a new one from style in a div

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm sorry for that title not very precise. Actually I have the following problem. I'd like to bring a value from a styled component (React with Styletron) to a css file via @property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property). However, the @property is linted with the following statement : "Unknown at rule @propertycss(unknownAtRules)" and isn't updating, taking the default value. You can find my code below :

CSS :

```
:root{
  --p:90;
}

@property --p {
  syntax: "<number>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: true;
}
```

React :

```
const Receipt: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const style = { '--p ': 20 } as React.CSSProperties;
  return (
      <div className="pie" style={style}/>
  );
};

export default Receipt;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm note quite clear - what value is --p ending up with? And what browser are you on?

Comment: Actually p will be used to design a circular range (p is for percentage) and the value will be used for a keyframe. Here you can find an example : https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/XWaPXZO . I'm on google chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question. Given the code in your question, what value does --p end up with?

Comment: Sorry to reply after 20 hours, well p will have for example a value of 80 and can be used for that line : ```transform: rotate(calc(var(--p)*3.6deg)) translateY(calc(50% - 124px/2));``` and that one too : ```animation:p 1s .5s both;``` Don't hesitate to tell me if I wasn't precise enough

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to rephrase. Your code has 3 possible values for --p, 90, 0, 20. Which value is --p actually ending up with?

Comment: Ah ok I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Actually I'd like --p to be 20. If --p isn't declared then it takes the value 90 and 0 is for the animation. The problem is that --p is ending up with 20.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, it's ending up with 90 while I'd like it to end up with 20

Comment: Ah, that's not what a simple version of your code produces as an inline style will overwrite stuff from the stylesheet. How are you testing the value of --p? I guess you realise that inline setting will only set it for that element (and its descendants?), it won't change the :root value.

Comment: Actually I put the --p in root because I read it's considered as a good practice to do it that way. However, even when --p was in the class "pie", I had the same issue.

Comment: Where are you using that --p?

Comment: I'm using --p in the pie classname of my css file. Btw I'm sorry I forgot to answer to one of your questions, I can test the value of --p with a circular range where its value corresponds to --p. That's how I can see that the value isn't updating.

Comment: You are setting the --p for that element, not for the class. The --p isn't a global (despite a --p being set a value in :root). If an element sets a property (albeit of the same name) that property has that value just for that element (and its descendants). So using the class 'inside' that element things will be fine, using it elsewhere it'll pick up the value set for ;root.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, even if I put --p: 90 in the class "pie" I still have the same problem, the value of p is 90 and not 20.

Comment: Yes, it will be. Changing --p inline within an element does not change anything directly in a class. It changes --p for that element and descendants.

Comment: Ok I see, then do you have any idea to fix that issue? Because even if I'm able to understand the concept I'm a bit lost right now